# Getting link to an action?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an action in a MobileController called 'myaction' and I call it with javascript like so:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function SubmitData() {

        $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost:1613/Mobile/myaction",
                data: "id to post",
                success:
                function (result) {
                    window.alert("SUCCESS");
                },
                error: function (req, status, error) {
                    window.alert("ERROR!");
                }
            }
            );
    }
</script>
```

Notice however the url is not using relative paths, I tried making it just ~/Mobile/myaction but that didn't work.

Any ideas how I can make it so the url being pointed to will work in all cases and not just if the domain is localhost:1613? Like if I uploaded it to mysite.com it would find the action at mysite.com/mobile/myaction.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: try just calling action like myaction it all about the path of url nice way to truck it is by using the web-console in Firefox and see the requesting URL

Comment: Relative URL's do work! Can you inspect your ajax call in Firebug and check what URL is being invoked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the url by:

```
url: "/Mobile/myaction"
```

With `~` sign, it will only work with server controls/functions.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried:

```
url: "@Url.Action(....)",
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 url: "@Url.Content("~/appName/Mobile/myaction/")"
```

Html::"/appName/Mobile/myaction/"
I suggest you to give your app Virtual path "/appName" doing this i'll allow you to avoid appName in url

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
new UrlHelper( HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext ).Action( "<action>", "<controller>", new { id = 1 } )
```

I'm using this exactly to pass values to a javascript function